# Remote Desktop with resource sharing

Tags: memory, remote-desktop, cpu, resources

I recently removed ubuntu from my laptop and installed Windows 7 because Microsoft's DreamSpark program gave me Visual Studio Pro for free and I want to do some C# programming with it.

The problem is that my laptop's screen is small, it's resources are extremely limited, and it doesn't have a full sized keyboard. However, I do have a desktop that is my primary system, and it's got a quadcore and tons of RAM in it, and dual monitors.

My question is this, is there a way I can use a program from my laptop, on my desktop, and share my desktops CPU and RAM with the laptop? Everything is connected through a 100 MB/s switch.

One caveat, my desktop is running ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a program like [Synergy+](http://synergy2.sourceforge.net/) to use your desktop's keyboard and mouse to control your laptop.  Synergy works over the network and makes transitioning from one system to the other seamless.

However, programs run on the laptop still run on the laptop's hardware.  There isn't a way for your desktop to "loan" CPU and RAM to your laptop.  You can setup network shares to allow the laptop to work on the desktop's files, or the desktop to work on the laptop's files, but a program started on one machine will not use any CPU or RAM from the other machine.

If your laptop is *that* limited, look into running a Windows 7 virtualmachine on your desktop, with software like [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/) or [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) or similar.

Comment: Like the Virtual Box option.
You could also set it to dual boot if you liked.

Answer (score 0):

...that is a sure way to failure.. Just install some grid software and all the cpu-s on your network will give you their resources, heck you can also use some newer gpu-s for program execution trough OpenAL. Just make sure you set the package size to variable from tine to sligtly bigger depending on your network configuration giving priority to faster machines and voila. Or alternatively use it remotely trough some VNC client like TightVNC or TeamViewer show the destination of your builds to yours host process by double-clicking on the remote desktop.

Comment: What is the sure way to failure?  VMs?